# jQuery Tablesorter not working with ajax

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to be able to sort a table that is generated every 1 second by javascript via ajax(table contents generated form xml)..for displaying autoupdating statuses.

I cannot get jQuery tablesorter to work.

I call this every time an update occurs(every 1 second). It appears to be running and there are no errors in the firefox console. The table is rendered properly(and updating)

```
//imports in head tag
<script type="text/javascript" src="./support/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./support/jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

updateTable(newXML); //here the table is generated and set to innerhtml of a div tag.
$("table").tablesorter({sortList:[[0,1],[1,1]]});
```

Essentialy, I expect my first 2 columns to be sorted descending, but they are not.

Here is my table tag, and I do not see any errors in my html that gets generated after this.

```
"<table id='mytable' width=650 class=\"tablesorter\"><tr id='headRow'>" +
```

Answer (score 2):

according to the http://tablesorter.com/docs/ :

> tablesorter is a jQuery plugin for turning a standard HTML table with
>   THEAD and TBODY tags into a sortable table without page refreshes.

i think you need `<thead>` and `<tbody>`